# Set keyboard interaction focus to a MenuFlyoutItem

Tags: uwp, accessibility, tabstop, keyboard-focus

In a `UWP` app I have used `MenuFlyoutItem` to show drop down list. Here is `xaml` code

```
    <DropDownButton Style="{StaticResource DropDownButtonStyle1}" Name="MyDropDownButton" 
                Content="{Binding SelectedLanguage}" 
                RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True" 
                Margin="0,20,20,0" 
                FontSize="14">
        <DropDownButton.Flyout>
            <MenuFlyout x:Name="OptionMenu"
                        Placement="BottomEdgeAlignedRight">
            </MenuFlyout>
        </DropDownButton.Flyout>
    </DropDownButton>
```

Programmatically i am adding `MenuFlyoutItem` to `MenuFlyout`

```
foreach (Option option in _viewModel.Options)
{
    MenuFlyoutItem item = new MenuFlyoutItem();
    item.Text = option.text;
    LanguagesMenu.Items.Add(item);
}
```

**Problem:** When user use app with keyboard interaction the first `MenuFlyoutItem` is focused. I want  different item to get focused (may be user previously selected item should get focused).

**Example:**

I have 3 option:

1. Left
2. Right
3. Bottom

When user open `MenuFlyout` by keyboard `Enter` its by default focused first item -> `Left`. I want 2nd item -> `Right` to be focused.

How can i achieve this. I have read [this Keyboard Interaction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/input/keyboard-interactions)  official doc but didn't find any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could directly use the [Control.Focus(FocusState) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control.focus?view=winrt-20348) to make the `MenuFlyoutItem` go to the focus state. I suggest you do this in the [Flyout.Opened Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.flyoutbase.opened?view=winrt-20348).

Based on your code, I made a simple demo and you might check it.

**Xaml:**

```
  <DropDownButton.Flyout>
            <MenuFlyout x:Name="OptionMenu"  Placement="BottomEdgeAlignedRight" Opened="OptionMenu_Opened">
            </MenuFlyout>
        </DropDownButton.Flyout>
```

**Code behind:**

```
private void OptionMenu_Opened(object sender, object e)
    {
        // let's say we need to set the seconed item as focused
        var list = OptionMenu.Items;
        MenuFlyoutItem item2 = list[1] as MenuFlyoutItem;

        item2.Focus(FocusState.Keyboard);
    }
```

**Update:**

Only make the item focused when the Enter key is pressed.

```
public Boolean IsKeyPressed = false;

  private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // same code 
        MenuFlyoutItem item = new MenuFlyoutItem();
        item.Text = "Left";

        MenuFlyoutItem item2 = new MenuFlyoutItem();
        item2.Text = "Right";

        MenuFlyoutItem item3 = new MenuFlyoutItem();
        item3.Text = "Bottom";

        OptionMenu.Items.Add(item);
        OptionMenu.Items.Add(item2);
        OptionMenu.Items.Add(item3);
        // handle the button keydown event.
        MyDropDownButton.PreviewKeyDown += MyDropDownButton_PreviewKeyDown;
    }

    private void MyDropDownButton_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //check if it is the Enter key
        if (e.Key == VirtualKey.Enter)
        {
            IsKeyPressed = true;
            Debug.WriteLine("Enter");
        }
        else 
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    private void OptionMenu_Opened(object sender, object e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Open");

        if (IsKeyPressed) 
        {
            // let's say we need to set the seconed item as focused
            var list = OptionMenu.Items;
            MenuFlyoutItem item2 = list[1] as MenuFlyoutItem;

            item2.Focus(FocusState.Keyboard);
            //reset the flag  
            // You could do this in other places if you want.
            IsKeyPressed = false;
        }
       
    }
```

Comment: Can I know `MenuFlyout` is opened via mouse `Click` or keyboard interaction `Enter` press  event ?

Comment: @AbuYousuf I have to say no, currently, I haven't found a way like that yet. You could submit a feature request in the Feedback Hub app about this.

Comment: Actually I need to Focus the selected item if user keyboard to navigate the views. Don't what to set focus when open menu by clicking. I can't differentiate that.

Comment: @AbuYousuf not quite understand the first scenario, maybe you could share a little bit more details with me?

Comment: User can interact with the `MenuFlyout` in 2 ways. 1.by mouse click 2. Keyboard Enter . I only want to set Focus ( `item2.Focus(FocusState.Keyboard)`) when user interact with Keyboard Enter key. Don't want to set focus `MenuFlyoutItem` when interact by Mouse Click.

Comment: @AbuYousuf OK. As I mentioned, there is no way to detect whether the menu button is opened by a click or the Enterkey. But a workaround for this is to handle the KeyDown event of the DropButton and make a flag to indicate if the Enter key is pressed. If it is, then you could set the focus in the Opened event.

Comment: @AbuYousuf I've updated my answer and please check that. Feel free to contact if you still have questions.